# Qt - new widget display not apparent?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm coming from Android development, and their approach to opening a new "activity" from a current one seems logical, and documented. Qt's does not.

Let's say I have the exact "QTabsExample", and inside one of these tabs is a button.  On button click, I want to get rid of all the tabs and open a different view...let's say an image view.  Why does there not seem to be one example out there for this?  Please help!

Comment: I guess you want to develop a mobile application? Most of Qt's documentation and examples is still desktop-centered, so I guess that's why there are not many examples for things like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you would want to use a [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qstackedwidget.html) in this case. A `QStackedWidget` manages a number of same sized "screens" that you can switch between, each having its own set of display widgets and buttons. Here is an [S60 example](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/d6287a35-5494-44af-abce-f65637c6b0b9/Qt_for_S60_QStackedWidget_Example.html), hopefully it will apply to your situation but you should be able to find more info on using `QStackedWidget`s.

Comment: +1 for QStackedWidget. I was going to post an answer using QtabWidget and the removeTab method. But this answer is a much better solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the container of the widget a better solution is to send a signal to the window and the window will then swap the main containers, otherwise things can get nasty if you try to delete  / remove the parent object from the child action method.